# How to check if the numbers aren't the same value while using random generator(srand,rand)

Tags: c++

The program needs to have 8 random numbers and the range I've written in the program below. There shouldn't be any commas behind the last number that is written out.

**On the end it needs to check the random numbers so that their values aren't the same. This is the part that is bothering me.**

I was trying to find a solution on my own for about 1-2 hours, after that I asked my friend for help.My friend said I should use this:
2 for clauses, one within the other and an if clause inside.

```
int tabela[8];
srand(time(0));

for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    tabela[i] = rand() % 20+1;
}

for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    cout << tabela[i];
    if (i<7) cout << ",";

// 2 for clauses, one within the other
// if clause

}
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance! Sorry for bad English.

Comment: a set can't have multiple identical numbers, so you could repeatedly insert your random numbers into a std::set<int> until the size of the set is 8... there are ways you could do it with std::array/vector and std::find, as well as many more.

Comment: Never let the chance to suggest a [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg) solution be heard: [something like this](http://ideone.com/spQ8ln). Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force:

```
// start with empty table:
int* first = std::begin(tabela);

do {
    // fill end of table with random values:
    std::for_each(first, std::end(tabela),
        [](int& x) { x = std::rand() % 20 + 1; });
    // sort and remove duplicates:
    std::sort(std::begin(tabela), std::end(tabela));
    first = std::unique(std::begin(tabela), std::end(tabela));
    // repeat until done:
} while (first != std::end(tabela));
```

Probably cleaner and faster for 8 values selected from a range of 20:

```
// generate range of values from 1 to 20:
int values[20];
std::iota(std::begin(values), std::end(values), 1);

// randomize the values:
std::random_shuffle(std::begin(values), std::end(values));

// select the first 8:
int tabela[8];
std::copy_n(std::begin(values), 8, std::begin(tabela));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with using STL, you can check whether the array contains a pair of equal numbers by subsequently applying sort() and unique() to it, and then comparing the sizes. Here is an example:

```
std::array<int> u(tabela, tabela + sizeof(tabela));
std::sort(u.begin(), u.end());
u.erase(std::unique(u.begin(), u.end()), u.end());
bool hasCollisions = u.size() != sizeof(tabela);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the for-for-if-loop you can compare every number with every other number.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 8; j++)
        if (tabela[i] == tabela[j])
            cout << tabela[i] << " exist more often than once!\nNeed to restart!";
```

If you check every number with every other, yet existing number, during the generation, than you would save the time you would need to create the rest of the numbers.

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Pretty sure they will match when i == j.

Answer (score 0):

Using the STL here are two different solutions that would simplify things a bit (working example https://ideone.com/X4lSj1):

Edit: this assumes you need 8 random numbers without repeat. you might want 8 random numbers, with repeats erased. i couldn't quite tell from your question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 randomEngine(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 21);

    std::set<int> setInts;
    while(setInts.size() < 8)
    {
        setInts.insert(distribution(randomEngine));
    }

    std::cout << "Using Set (sorted)" << std::endl;
    for(const auto currInt : setInts)
    {
        std::cout << currInt << '\n';
    }

    std::vector<int> vectorInts;
    while(vectorInts.size() < 8)
    {
        const auto randomNumber = distribution(randomEngine);
        if (std::find(vectorInts.begin(), vectorInts.end(), randomNumber) == vectorInts.end())
        {
            vectorInts.push_back(randomNumber);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nUsing Vectors (unsorted)" << std::endl;
    for(const auto currInt : vectorInts)
    {
        std::cout << currInt << '\n';
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Test Output:
Using Set (sorted)
1
3
4
5
10
11
12
14

Using Vectors (unsorted)
3
18
14
16
15
1
8
4